# how to save list of string in csv without apostrophe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

so what I want to do is to save list of strings into a cell in csv file in python.
when I try saving this using `pd.to_csv('file.csv')` the output is like this:

```
date,content
20, "['banana', 'apple',...]"
```

I want to save the list without apostrophe like this:

```
date, content
20, "[banana, apple, ...]"
```

Any help would be thankful.

+
here are some codes I used for generating the list.

```
abstracts = []
for t in tdf_groupby_date:
    nested_list = t[1].to_list() # nested list
    flat_list = [item for sublist in nested_list for item in sublist] # flat list
    abstracts.append(flat_list)
```

[t is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5KMS.png)

+
I solved this issue.
I converted the list into string type and deleted the apostophe and others.
The suggestions you gave were right but my problem here was that doesn't convert still.
so I used another function for converting and it worked!
here are some codes I used just FYI in the future.
\

```
def convert_list_to_str(data):
    data = str(data)
    data = data.replace("'",'')
    data = data.replace(' ','')
    data = data.replace('[','')
    data = data.replace(']','')
    
    return data

df['abstracts'] = df.abstracts.apply(convert_list_to_str)
```

Comment: You need to join the substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: seems like I forgot that content is not a normal variable. It should be as below.

```
df["content"] = str(df["content"]).replace("'","")
```

---

Try this before you do pd.to_csv('file.csv'):

```
content = str(content).replace("'","")
```

Comment: then it goes None.

Comment: could you share the relavant portion of the code that includes the generation of the list of strings. i'll troubleshoot it from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the string replace function from pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [20,], "content": ["['banana', 'apple']", ]})

df
   date              content
0    20  ['banana', 'apple']

df.content = df.content.str.replace("'", "")

df
   date          content
0    20  [banana, apple]

df.to_csv("file.csv")
```